# Why is flask throwing a class attribute error

Tags: python, flask

My flask app is telling me that the method of a class I created is not defined. It says:

AttributeError: 'GetIndexItemInfo' object has no attribute 'genDFs'

Here is the code:

**__init__.py**

```
    @app.route('/assistant', methods=['GET', 'POST'])
    @login_required
    def use_assistant():
        from flask import request

        if request.method == 'GET':
            ...FORM GOES HERE

        else:
            report = request.form.get('report')
            from modules.majestic import config
            rprt = config[report]
            inst=rprt(request.form)
            url = inst.genUrl()
            dic = inst.getData(url)

            df = inst.genDFs(dic)            
            ...
```

**majestic.py**

```
import urllib.request, urllib.parse, urllib.error 
import ast
import pandas as pd
import ssl

ctx = ssl.create_default_context() 
ctx.check_hostname = False  
ctx.verify_mode = ssl.CERT_NONE 

class Majestic:
    key='APIKEYHERE'
    base='https://api.majestic.com/api/json?app_api_key={}'.format(key)

    @staticmethod    
    def getData(url):
        req = urllib.request.Request(url=url)
        f = urllib.request.urlopen(req, context=ctx)        
        x = f.read().decode('utf-8')
        dic = ast.literal_eval(x)
        return dic

class Report(Majestic):
    def __init__(self,data):

        items=[]
        for key,val in data.items():
            if 'address' in key:
                items.append(val)
        self.items = items
        self.len = len(items)
        self.cmd = data['cmd']        
        self.base_url = super().base

    def genUrl(self):
        substr=self.base_url+'&cmd='+self.cmd+'&items='+str(len(self.items))+'&'
        for i,item in enumerate(self.items):
            substr=substr+'item'+str(i)+'='+item+'&'

        return substr[:-1]


class GetIndexItemInfo(Report):

    @staticmethod
    def genDfs(data):
        for i in range(len(data['DataTables']['Results']['Data'])):
            new_data=data['DataTables']['Results']['Data'][i]
            cols = ['Url','AC Rank','Citation Flow','Trust Flow','Ext. Back Links','Ref Domains','Ref Follow Domains']
            maj_cols = ['Item','ACRank','CitationFlow','TrustFlow','ExtBackLinks','RefDomains','RefDomainTypeFollow']
            dic = dict(zip(cols,[new_data[i] for i in maj_cols]))
            cols = ['Url','AC Rank','Citation Flow','Trust Flow','Ext. Back Links','Ref Domains','Ref Follow Domains']
            if i == 0:
                main_df = pd.DataFrame(dic,index=[0])[cols]
            else:
                df = pd.DataFrame(dic,index=[0])[cols]
                main_df = main_df.append(df, ignore_index=True)
        return main_df
```

I have tested majestic.py seperately and the class instance of GetIndexItemInfo I create works as expected and does not return the error.

Any ideas why i might be getting this error when i run it in flask?

Many thanks in advance

Answer (score 4, accepted):

It is correct. 
AttributeError: 'GetIndexItemInfo' object has no attribute `'genDFs'`

Your method is called `genDfs`
Notice the capitalisation.